# Submitting to the app store while in prototype stages

Tags: ios, xcode, appstore-approval, prototyping

Is it possible to submit a prototype app to the app store while still developing the finished product?

Comment: I'm voting this as off-topic because it doesn't _really_ have to do with code and programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because app store submission policy is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/65839) and better addressed by Apple support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question which should be asked of the Customer Service department for the company you are dealing with. Please see: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) and [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/).

Answer (score 2):

According to the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/): no.

> 2.2 Beta Testing
>   Demos, betas, and trial versions of your app don’t belong on the App Store – use TestFlight instead. Any app submitted for beta distribution via TestFlight should be intended for public distribution and should comply with the App Review Guidelines. Note, however, that apps using TestFlight cannot be distributed to testers in exchange for compensation of any kind, including as a reward for crowd-sourced funding. Significant updates to your beta build should be submitted to TestFlight App Review before being distributed to your testers. To learn more, visit the TestFlight Beta Testing.

But if you call it a finished product and if it's as good as a finished product then yes. If you're marketing as a prototype, then refer to Apple's message above.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.You can submit your app to app store. But, you want to make sure that you want to publish your App to Normal user or Not. IF you want to distribute for External tester then no need to send application for Approval. You can upload .ipa file and distribute to External Testers.